# Getting results not to time out using PHP and MYSql with large amount of database data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that reads order information from a JSON file and then writes changes and updates to my database

this is the basics of the code i have

```
//variables and arrays set up from JSON file
$a_ds = array();
    $a_vs = array();
    $ad_ds = array();
    $ad_vs = array();
    $am_ds = array();
    $am_vs = array();
    $key = $lines['ORDER_NUMBER'].$lines['LINE_NUMBER'];

    // TABLE ARTICLE
    $a_ds[] = 'CUSTOMER_NUMBER'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['CUSTOMER_NUMBER']."'";
    $a_ds[] = 'ORDER_NUMBER'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['ORDER_NUMBER']."'";
    $a_ds[] = 'TYPE'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['TYPE']."'";
    $a_ds[] = 'LINE_NUMBER'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['LINE_NUMBER']."'";
    $a_ds[] = 'REFERENCE_TEXT'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['REFERENCE_TEXT']."'";
    $a_ds[] = 'ARTICLE_NUMBER'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['ARTICLE_NUMBER']."'";
    $a_ds[] = 'ORDER_DATE'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['ORDER_DATE']."'";
    $a_ds[] = 'QUANTITY'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['QUANTITY']."'";
    $a_ds[] = 'PRICE'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['PRICE']."'";
    $a_ds[] = 'ORDER_STATUS'; $a_vs[] = "'".$lines['ORDER_STATUS']."'";


    $table_name = 'ORDER_STATUS';


//check to see if order number exists

    $checkQuery = "SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM order_status WHERE ORDER_NUMBER = '".$lines['ORDER_NUMBER']."'";

    $checkResult = mysql_query($checkQuery) or error($checkQuery."\n".mysql_error());



    //perform update or insert depending on existance
    if (mysql_fetch_row($checkResult)) {
        $querys[] = "update ".$table_name." set ".join(', ', $a_s)." where concat(ORDER_NUMBER, LINE_NUMBER) = '".$key."'";
    } else {
        $querys[] = "insert into ".$table_name." (".join(', ', $a_ds).") values(".join(', ', $a_vs).")";
    }
}

//run queries
    if (true) {
    if ($querys) {
        foreach ($querys as $query) {
            $result = mysql_query($query) or error($query."\n".mysql_error());
        }
    }
} else {
    if ($querys) {
        echo join(";\n", $querys);
        die();
    }
```

this all seems to work fine if i just echo the sql queries the problem i have is if i try and actually execute the query

The JSON file returns almost 35,000 separate orders and the database holds 32,000 separate lines in database for orders

I know there must be a better way of doing this but my PHP and SQL knowledge is very limited

I have tried getting all the order numbers into a PHP array and using in_array but this works just the same all that happens is the page just times out

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Aside: the `mysql_*` extension is basically obsolete.

Comment: Could I suggest you do this as a terminal job using PHP CLI or maybe CRON then there is no timeout to worry about

Comment: You could probably reduce this to a single `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` type query.

Comment: Or add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 1000);` to the top of your script. Unless your hosting company have blocked this statement

Comment: CD001 im not sure if this will work as each separate item in an order has a row in the table i am trying to update so there would be lots of row that are duplicate there is a row number field in the table that auto increments for each entry per order number

Comment: Apart from what  @CD001 is stating (which is absolutely the case; I'm surprised people are still using PHP 4 extensions),  this could be a database issue.  How long does the query take directly in the database?  Is ORDER_NUMBER indexed? It appears (just by the look of your query) that everything may be being stored on a massive table...

Comment: nomistic you are right everything is on 1 large table unfortunately the reason for the version of PHP is just the server and database not worth changing it for what it does at the moment.

Comment: I have looked at using INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but the key is concat and cant figure out how to reference this in the sql query as i know i cant use the where concat(ORDER_NUMBER, LINE_NUMBER) = '".$key."' i have in my current update